# new vector creation in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, vector

This is a sample of my dataset.  The code I am running is: 
sum(df.Survived ==df.ModelPrediction) 
but I'm getting a return of '0', which is obviously incorrect.  Can anyone advise?  Both variables are objects.

[image]

Comment: Could be the spelling error. ModelPredication instead of ModelPrediction. Just pointing out that its wrong if that's your code.

Comment: hi!  Yes, sorry, typo wasn't there is the code, now corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like:

```
df[df.Survived == df.ModelPrediction].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are shorter methods to do that but to simplify(easy to understand) you can iterate over the dataframe and count how many lines have the "nature" you want to return.

```
cnt = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['Survived'] == row['ModelPredication']:
        cnt = cnt + 1
return cnt
```